# Ошибка "Timeout Expired". Не могу соединиться с Microsoft SQL Server Express

Tags: delphi

Microsoft Sql Server 2012 Express.

Delphi 10.2

Имя компьютера SERVER-EDEL

в Database management Studio проходит аутентификацию по user name -sa и  password -mari

в Firedac Connection Editor заполняю:

```
Database: D:\DirectDll\MSSQL\Base_central.mdf или просто 'Base_Central'
User name:sa 
password mari
Address: 1433 или без него
```

Server: пробовал по-разному:

```
SERVER-EDEL\MSSQLSERVER
SERVER-EDEL
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1\MSSQLSERVER
SERVER-EDEL\MSSQLSERVER, 1433
OsAuthent: No
```

выводит: **Timeout Expired**

Порт в Firewall открытий.

```
СТраница Info компонента FDConnection:
    ================================
    Connection definition parameters
    ================================
    Database=D:\DirectDll\MSSQL\Base_central.mdf
    Server=SERVER-EDEL\ MSSQLSERVER
    OSAuthent=No
    User_Name=sa
    Password=*****
    DriverID=MSSQL
    ================================
    FireDAC info
    ================================
    Tool = RAD Studio 10.2
    FireDAC = 16.0.0 (Build 88974)
    Platform = Windows 32 bit
    Defines = FireDAC_NOLOCALE_META;FireDAC_MONITOR
    ================================
    Client info
    ================================
    Loading driver MSSQL ...
     Loading odbc32.dll driver manager
     Creating ODBC environment handle
     Searching for ODBC driver ...
     Checking for ODBC driver [SQL SERVER NATIVE CLIENT 11.0] ...
     Found [SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
    ================================
    Session info
    ================================
    Failed to connect to DBMS !
    Timeout expired
```

Что ещё можно сделать!!!!!

Comment: А у Вас включена на сервере [SQL Server аутентификация](https://belkasoft.com/images/bec/help/SqlServerMixedAuthenticationMode.jpg)?

Comment: указывать путь к mdf файлу это странный путь, который не должен работать. имя базы на сервере может не соответствовать имени файла. если отпадает по таймауту, то отключите вообще фаерволл.